# Validate if JSON index exist in google app script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been developing a webhook that receives a json file from a shopify store in google app script. This json file changes its available index depending on what was chosen by the client during checkout. Therefore, before using an index from the json file, I would like to validate its existence. Below you will find some ideas I have on solving it.

**Do you know if there is some way of ensuring that an index exists on a json file for google app script?**

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(payload.postData.contents);
  
  if (parsedData.has("shipping_address"))
  {
    
    sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.shipping_address.name]);
    sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.order_number]);
    sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.shipping_address.city]);
    sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.shipping_address.phone]);
    sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.shipping_address.company]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that in your script, you might want to use `hasOwnProperty()`. So, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
      if (parsedData.has("shipping_address"))
    ```
  - To

    ```
      if (parsedData.hasOwnProperty("shipping_address"))
    ```
  - In this case, I thought that `if ("shipping_address" in parsedData)` can be also used.
- In your script, if `sheetName` is the sheet object and you want to put the values to a row, please modify your 5 `sheetName.appendRow()` as follows.

  - From

    ```
      sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.shipping_address.name]);
      sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.order_number]);
      sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.shipping_address.city]);
      sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.shipping_address.phone]);
      sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.shipping_address.company]);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.shipping_address.name, parsedData.order_number, parsedData.shipping_address.city, parsedData.shipping_address.phone, parsedData.shipping_address.company]);
    ```

#### References:

- [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)
- [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tanaike, it worked perfectly, at the end the code looked like the following:

```
if (parsedData.hasOwnProperty('shipping_address'))
{
   sheetName.appendRow([parsedData.shipping_address.name, parsedData.order_number, 
   parsedData.shipping_address.city, parsedData.shipping_address.phone, 
   parsedData.shipping_address.company]);
}
```